# function executed twice after checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, checkbox

I use the below code

```
$("#cc1").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
    //somefunction
});
```

in order to execute a function after cc1 button is clicked. With this code everything works great.

When I use the below code

```
$("#cc1").unbind('click').click(function(e) {

    if($('#cc').is(':checked')){

    }

    //somefunction
});
```

in order to execute the same function as above but when cc checkbox is checked and button pay is clicked the function is executed more than once and I receive errors in db reading...

What is the problem?

when pay button is clicked the app passes some vars to a function in order to update - import data into a db. If cc is checked the app passes different data.
The above page contains a button (pay) that when is pressed the payment is made by cash. If cc is checked the payment is made by credit card.

Comment: check this: `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

Comment: Could you try to provide a snippet that we can run to reproduce your problem?

Comment: If `#pay` button a submit button?

Comment: I'm suspicious of the need to unbind / rebind.  There's probably a cleaner way... what are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: @cale_b yeah, wouldn't implementing `click` just replace the old one?

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL why not `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: No, you can bind multiple click events, which is why I'm suspicious why it's needed (suspecting a logic / design flaw) - I suspect that's what's going on here - multiple click events being bound.

Comment: @kosbou Is this a typo or does your first code snippet use `$('#cc1')` while your second code snippet uses `$('#pay')`?

Comment: @Gasmin because `e.preventDefault()` stop the default behavior, and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` avoids the event from bubbling up.

Comment: @Gasim I try to reach at the same result. The 1st snippet is using a button. The second is using another button in addition with a checkbox

Comment: Try unbind() without any parameters to see if the even handlers are cleaned out.

Comment: @dliu can you suggest a snippet for this?

Comment: Is the button acting as a submit button? maybe try change the unbind event from `click` to `submit`. As for dliu's suggestion, it would be the same but with no parameter passed to `unbind()` like `.unbind().click()`

Comment: @adjit no luck same result

Comment: @adjit no luck same result

Comment: Have you tried `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` or `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @adjit no luck the same result with e.stopImmediatePropagation() or e.preventDefault()

Comment: And you're passing 'e' to the click function?

Comment: If you want us to be able to help you, provide us with your HTML, so we can replicate your error. Just the HTML of the form is enough

Comment: You can set a breakpoint at the place where the data is submitted, and see how many time the breakpoint is reached. Then you will know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, may be the following code can help you:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <form id="form">
        <input type="button" name="cc1" value="cc1" id="cc1">     
        <input type="button" name="pay" value="pay" id="pay">    
        <input type="checkbox" name="cc" id="cc">     
      </form>
 <script>

$("#cc1").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
      //somefunction
  alert("test cc1");
    });

$("#pay").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
     if($('#cc').is(':checked')){
       //somefunction
       alert("credit");
     }
     else{
       //anotherfunction
       alert("cash");
    }
   }); 
</script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem would appear if you have a dynamic listener being bound & this condition happens. This would trigger 2x clicks, as the 2nd listener doesn't have an unbind on it. These clicks stack.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cc1"> Double Click<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cc2"> Single Click
```

JS: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/3Ljjy6jr/)

```
// Static Listener
$("#cc1").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
   checkClicked($(this));
});
$("#cc2").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
   checkClicked($(this));
});

/* Dynamic Listener - Typically happens when Ajax data is being loaded,   
 * DOM nodes are being added & listeners are being re-attached to the 
 * new form fields:
 */
$("#cc1").click(function(e) { // .unbind('click')
  checkClicked($(this));
});
$("#cc2").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
  checkClicked($(this));
});

function checkClicked(chkBx) {
  console.log('clicked');
  if(chkBx.prop('checked')){
    console.log('isChecked: yes');
  } else {
    console.log('isChecked: no');
  }
}
```

So make sure that your code doesn't have incorrect dynamic listeners being attached to it. If .unbind('click') is added to the 2nd dynamic listener, then it'll only have 1 click action.

Oh, btw: .is(':checked') doesn't work in jQuery. You'll have to use .prop('checked') to get the true/false condition on the checkbox.